# Вывод последних 3-ех комментариев [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с комментариями. Хочу вывести последние 3, но в порядке возрастания. Как в ВК например. Не 3.2.1 , а 1.2.3.

Мой код:

```
SELECT * FROM `prefix_comments` ORDER by `comment_date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Как быть?

Comment: select * from (SELECT * FROM `prefix_comments` ORDER by `comment_date` DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER by `comment_date`

Comment: Как я сразу не догадался то! :D.. СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение от [**splash58**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58:)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `prefix_comments` ORDER by `comment_date` DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER by `comment_date`
```